# How do I not download pdf when I click on the url through the mobile?

Tags: laravel, iframe, bootstrap-modal

I created an application to organize records, the list has some pdf links, when I access the domain through a computer, the pdf is opened in a new tab and everything happens normally, but when I access from a cell phone (Android specifically) the File is downloaded. Is there a way to prevent this download from being made? I thought about using an iFrame that displays the content, but first I would like to know if there is an alternative to deflect this problem.

**My table with pdf url**

```
<table class="table">
          <tr>
            <th>Data</th>
            <th>Nº Pedido</th>
            <th>Cliente</th>
            <th>Valor</th>
            <th>Pedido</th>
            <th>Serasa</th>
            <th>Histórico</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th></th>
          </tr>
          @foreach($orders as $value)
          <tr>
            <td>{{date_format($value->created_at,'d-m-Y')}}</td>
            <td>{{$value->ph_pedido}}</td>
            <td>{{substr($value->ph_cliente,0,15)}}...</td>
            <td>R${{ number_format($value->ph_valor, 2, '.', '')}}</td>
            <td><a href="{{$value->ph_urlpdf}}" target="_blank" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Clique para acessar"data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Tooltip on top">@if($value->ph_urlpdf == null)<img src="https://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/comercio-urbano/Product/marcas/tycoontech/647716-pdf-24.png"> @else <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/document-icons-2/30/647716-pdf-24.png" alt="">@endif</a></td>
            <td><a href="{{$value->ph_urlserasa}}" target="_blank" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Clique para acessar">@if($value->ph_urlserasa == null)<img src="https://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/comercio-urbano/Product/marcas/tycoontech/647716-pdf-24.png"> @else <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/document-icons-2/30/647716-pdf-24.png" alt="">@endif</a></td>
            <td><a href="{{$value->ph_historico}}" target="_blank" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Clique para acessar">@if($value->ph_historico == null)<img src="https://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/comercio-urbano/Product/marcas/tycoontech/647716-pdf-24.png"> @else <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/document-icons-2/30/647716-pdf-24.png" alt="">@endif</a></td>
            @if(Auth::user()->admin == 1)
            <td>
              @if($value->ph_approved == 1)
              <a href="orders/approve/{{$value->ph_orderid}}"><label class="label label-success">Aprovado</label></a>
              @elseif($value->ph_approved == 0)
              <a href="orders/approve/{{$value->ph_orderid}}"><label class="label label-danger">Não aprovado</label></a>
              @elseif($value->ph_approved == 3)
              <a href="orders/approve/{{$value->ph_orderid}}"><label class="label label-warning">Pendente</label></a>
              @endif
            </td>
            @else
            <td>
              @if($value->ph_approved == 1)
              <label class="label label-success">Aprovado</label>
              @elseif($value->ph_approved == 0)
              <label class="label label-danger">Não aprovado</label>
              @elseif($value->ph_approved == 3)
              <label class="label label-warning">Pendente</label>
              @endif
            </td>
            @endif
            <tr>
            @endforeach
            </table>
```

Any suggestion? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think it has nothing to do with your code. Default behaviour is fine. Tell me if you are able to open PDF in your mobile browser? I guess since the browser can not handle showing PDF, tries to download that.

Comment: I finded a solution, if I answer my own questions the stackoverflow is gonna punish me for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finded the solution, if I add the code `http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=` before my link, I gonna redirect my link to google docs and that allow me see the document instead of downloaded.